# Guava Load Multiple Keys and Get multiple items

Tags: java, guava

I would like to use Guava as cache but I can't seem to find Guava has the capability of allowing me to load multiple items and get multiple items.

I see CacheLoader has the following:

```
    @Override
    public Value load(String key) {
        return getKey();
    }
```

And what I need to load is:

```
    @Override
    public List<Value> load(List<String> keys) {
        return getKeys();
    }
```

I would also expect to get one or a list of items from the cache, but I am happy even if I had to wrap that one item into a list just to get it.

I'm new to Guava and I'm not sure if Guava has such functionality?

Comment: That's the CacheLoader class right?

Comment: Correct, CacheLoader. Is there any other cache provided by guava that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Not as far as I can see. I'm not familiar with this class, but I wanted to take a look. As a general rule I'd put as much info in a question as necessary.

Comment: Appreciated for trying to help.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`CacheLoader.loadAll()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#loadAll-java.lang.Iterable-) to load multiple items, and [`LoadingCache.getAll()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#getAll-java.lang.Iterable-) to get them.

For example:

```
new CacheLoader<String, Value>() {
    @Override
    public Value load(String key) {
        return getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Value> load(Iterable<? extends String> keys) {
        return getKeys();
    }
}
//...
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2", "key3");
ImmutableMap<String, Value> values = cache.getAll(keys);
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I am seeking for... what I would like to have is to have all keys store on the same map. EX:

LIst<String>Keys = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2", "key3");
ImmutableMap<String, Value> value = cache.getAll(keys);
cache.get("key1") //<--- I expect this not to issue a call to getKey().

Comment: I expect the same. Why would it cache the same key twice?

Comment: I think I should state my request in this way: 

What I want to load are four different keys in two different ways:
Hashamp<String, Values> map = new Hashmap<>();
map.add("key1", value1);
map.add("key2", value2);
String Key = "key4";

cache.load(keys)
cache.load(key)

When I retrieve the keys, I would like to retrieve in two different ways:
cache.getAll() // which returns me value1, value2, value3, value4

Comment: It's still not very clear what you're asking for. If you want to explicitly add entries to a Cache, you can use `Cache.asMap()` to do so. If you want to delegate the lookup to a separate hashmap, that's just an implementation detail in your loading methods.

Comment: you are storing two different set of keys. One set are String keys, and another set are List of Strings keys.

Comment: correct, so I have decided just to work away from Loading Cache, and work with Cache object directly.

Comment: `LoadingCache` **is** a `Cache`!

Comment: Yes I understand LoadingCache is a Cache. But the methods the two loads method are creating two different set of Keys in your Cache.

Comment: I don't know why you would think so.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`LoadingCache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html)(just for e.g.) as:

```
private final LoadingCache<String, Object> cache;
```

where String could be your key's datatype and Object could be your value's datatype.

You can then initialise it using CacheBuilder as:

```
cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().
                initialCapacity(10).
                maximumSize(50).
                recordStats().
                build(new CacheLoader<String, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object load(String s) throws Exception {
                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

and further more implement methods to get a value from the cache based on the key and put a value into the cache for a key value pair in somewhat this format:

```
public Object get(String key) {
    try {
        return cache.getIfPresent(key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean put(String key, Object object) {
    cache.put(key, object);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public class Cache { 
  private Cache<Key, Value> cache;
  prviate DataDAO cataDao;

  public Cache(DataDAO dataDao) {
     _dataDao = DataDAO;
     cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();
  }

  public Value getValue(Key key) {
     Value value;
     if (cache.getIfPresent(key) == null) {
         value = dataDao.getById(key);
         cache.put(key, value);
         return value;
     }else{
         return cache.getIfPresent(key);
     } 
  }

  Public List<Value> getValues(List<Key> keys) {
     List<Value> values = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Key> notInCacheKeys = new ArrayList<>();
     for (Key key: keys) {
        if (cache.getIfPresent(key)) == null) {
           notInCacheKeys.add(key);
        }
     }
     List<Value> newlyRetrievedValues = _dataDao.getByIds(notInCacheKeys);
     //Store Keys and Values in order
     //Return value and list of values from cache
  }
}
```

I have decided to abandon CacheLoader and LoadingCache and just work with cache directly.

Comment: But now if loading the value takes some time, you'll have multiple threads trying to load the value in parallel. LoadingCache, instead, blocks all threads but one. When the value is loaded all threads will be resumed with the loaded value.